# InvalidArgumentError: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

**Background**

I am totally new to Python and to machine learning. I just tried to set up a UNet from code I found on the internet and wanted to adapt it to the case I'm working on bit for bit. When trying to `.fit` the UNet to the training data, I received the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
     [[node Equal (defined at <ipython-input-68-f1422c6f17bb>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3847]
```

I get a lot of results when I search for it, but mostly they are different errors.

What does this mean? And, more importantly, how can I fix it?

**The code that caused the error**

The context of this error is as follows:
I want to segment images and label the different classes.
I set up directories "trn", "tst" and "val" for training, test, and validation data. The `dir_dat()` function applies `os.path.join()` to get the full path to the respective [data set](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g4yr4qjgjtsytmi/AABJXVehoCw5In9wQvL7Llu2a?dl=0). Each of the 3 folders has sub directories for each class labeled with integers. In each folder, there are some `.tif` images for the respective class.

I defined the following image data generators (training data is sparse, hence the augmentation):

```
classes = np.array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 11, 16, 21, 29, 30, 38, 39, 51])
bs = 15 # batch size

augGen = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 365,
                                                   width_shift_range = 0.05,
                                                   height_shift_range = 0.05,
                                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                                   vertical_flip = True,
                                                   fill_mode = "nearest") \
    .flow_from_directory(directory = dir_dat("trn"),
                         classes = [str(x) for x in classes.tolist()],
                         class_mode = "categorical",
                         batch_size = bs, seed = 42)
    
tst_batches = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator() \
    .flow_from_directory(directory = dir_dat("tst"),
                         classes = [str(x) for x in classes.tolist()],
                         class_mode = "categorical",
                         batch_size = bs, shuffle = False)

val_batches = ks.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator() \
    .flow_from_directory(directory = dir_dat("val"),
                         classes = [str(x) for x in classes.tolist()],
                         class_mode = "categorical",
                         batch_size = bs)
```

Then I set up the UNet based on [this example](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/074-Defining%20U-net%20in%20Python%20using%20Keras.py). Here, I altered a few parameters to adapt the UNet to the situation (multiple classes), namely activation in the last layer and the loss function:

```
layer_in = ks.layers.Input(shape = (imgr, imgc, imgdim))
# convert pixel integer values to float
inVals = ks.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(layer_in)

# Contraction path
c1 = ks.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(inVals)
c1 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = ks.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c1)
p1 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = ks.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(p1)
c2 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = ks.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c2)
p2 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
 
c3 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(p2)
c3 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c3)
p3 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
 
c4 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(p3)
c4 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c4)
p4 = ks.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(c4)
 
c5 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(p4)
c5 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = ks.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c5)

# Expansive path 
u6 = ks.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), padding = "same")(c5)
u6 = ks.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(u6)
c6 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = ks.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c6)
 
u7 = ks.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), padding = "same")(c6)
u7 = ks.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(u7)
c7 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = ks.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c7)
 
u8 = ks.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), padding = "same")(c7)
u8 = ks.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(u8)
c8 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = ks.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c8)
 
u9 = ks.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides = (2, 2), padding = "same")(c8)
u9 = ks.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis = 3)
c9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(u9)
c9 = ks.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = ks.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = "relu",
                            kernel_initializer = "he_normal", padding = "same")(c9)
 
out = ks.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation = "softmax")(c9)
 
model = ks.Model(inputs = layer_in, outputs = out)
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
model.summary()
```

Finally, I defined callbacks and ran the training, which produced the error:

```
cllbs = [
    ks.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience = 4),
    ks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(dir_out("Checkpoint.h5"), save_best_only = True),
    ks.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = './logs'),# log events for TensorBoard
    ]

model.fit(augGen, epochs = 5, validation_data = val_batches, callbacks = cllbs)
```

**Full console output**

This is the full output when running the last line (in case it helps solving the issue):

```
trained = model.fit(augGen, epochs = 5, validation_data = val_batches, callbacks = cllbs)
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-f1422c6f17bb>", line 1, in <module>
    trained = model.fit(augGen, epochs = 5, validation_data = val_batches, callbacks = cllbs)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1183, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3023, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1960, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 591, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(

  File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)
     [[node Equal (defined at <ipython-input-68-f1422c6f17bb>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3847]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found several issues here. The model was intended to be used for semantic segmentation with several classes (this is why I had changed the output layer activation to `"softmax"` and set `"sparse_categorical_crossentropy"` loss). Hence, in the ImageDataGenerators, `class_mode` has to be set to `None`. `classes` are not to be provided. Instead, I needed to insert the manually classified images as `y`. I guess beginners make a lot of beginner mistakes.

Answer (score 16):

I faced this problem when the number of Class Labels did not match with the shape of the Output Layer's output shape.

For example, if there are 10 Class Labels and we have defined the Output Layer as:

```
output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, (1, 1), activation = "softmax")(c9)
```

As the number of Class Labels (`10`) is not equal to the Output shape (`5`).
Then, we will get this error.

**Ensure that the number of class labels matches with the Output Layer's output shape.**

Answer (score 5):

Just add the ***Flatten()*** layer before the Fully Connected layers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: save me a lot time

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue because I used a number of n_classes in the model (for the output layer) different from the actual number of classes in the labels/masks array. I see you have a similar issue here: you have 13 classes, but your output layer is given only 1. The best way is to avoid hard-coding the number of classes, and only pass a variable (like n_classes) in the model, then declare this variable before calling the model. For instance n_classes = y_Train.shape[-1] or n_classes = len(np.unique(y_Train))

Answer (score 2):

Try to check whether `ks.layers.concatenate layers`' inputs are of equal dimension. For example `ks.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])`, here check u7 and c3 tensors are of same shape to be concatenated except the axis input to the function `ks.layers.concatenate`. `Axis = -1` default, that's the last dimension. To illustrate if you are giving `ks.layers.concatenate([u7,c3],axis=0)`, then except the first axis of both u7 and c3 all other axes' dimension should match exactly, example, `u7.shape = [3,4,5], c3.shape = [6,4,5].`

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same error, please check all your Concat layers and multiplication layers, or any layer where there is a similar operation happening.

This error is visible when there is a size mismatch and the model is not able to perform that operation.