# Custom loss function with a larger predefined tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to try to train a NN to do nonlinear fitting for me.

I generate a set of model parameters `p`, calculate the model output (the `y` values) on a given set of `x` values. The NN input is the `y` and output should be the predicted parameters `p'`.

Instead of using a loss function like the MSE between `p` and `p'`, I think it could work better to first generate the predicted `y'` and then use the MSE between `y` and `y'`. (I was having issues where small differences in some of the parameters could cause a massive "drift" in the fitted curve when x >> 0.)

I found that Keras uses symbolic evaluation of the loss function (I think?). Thus, I implemented a version of my model using Keras backend calls as follows:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=1000)

# regular model
def model(x, a):
    return np.cos(a * x)

def Kmodel(x, params):
    a = params[:, 0]
    # other parameters omitted, params[:, n]
    # simplified model for illustration
    return K.cos(a * x)

# THIS CAUSES ISSUES
keras_x = K.constant(x)

def regression_loss(p_true, p_pred):
    y_true = Kmodel(keras_x, p_true)
    y_pred = Kmodel(keras_x, p_pred)
    mse = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
    return mse
```

However, I can't figure out how to multiply everything by `x`. It involves increasing the dimensionality of the vectors, as we have 1000 values for `x` instead of however many parameters I am using. Keras does not like it:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1733] INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes

Graph execution error:
<snip>
File "/tmp/ipykernel_4109/793156309.py", line 9, in Kmodel
      return a * x
Node: 'regression_loss/mul'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node regression_loss/mul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_18838]
```

I found similar problems online, but none seem to deal with this broadcasting issue. For example, [Tensor indexing in custom loss function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200080/tensor-indexing-in-custom-loss-function), [Custom loss function in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818584/custom-loss-function-in-keras), [Is it possible to call/use instance attributes or global variables from a custom loss function using Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62090960/is-it-possible-to-call-use-instance-attributes-or-global-variables-from-a-custom), [InvalidArgumentError: required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67557515/invalidargumenterror-required-broadcastable-shapes-at-locunknown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, you just have to make sure that `a` has the same shape as `x`. For example, you can use `tf.repeat`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=1000)

# regular model
def model(x, a):
    return np.cos(a * x)

def Kmodel(x, params):
    a = tf.repeat(params[:, 0], repeats=tf.shape(x)[0] // tf.shape(params)[0])

    # other parameters omitted, params[:, n]
    # simplified model for illustration
    return tf.keras.backend.cos(a * x)

# THIS CAUSES ISSUES
keras_x = tf.keras.backend.constant(x)

def regression_loss(p_true, p_pred):
    y_true = Kmodel(keras_x, p_true)
    y_pred = Kmodel(keras_x, p_pred)
    mse = tf.keras.backend.mean(tf.keras.backend.square(y_true - y_pred))
    return mse

y_true = tf.constant([[0., 1.], [0., 0.]])
y_pred = tf.constant([[1., 1.], [1., 0.]])

regression_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.6316855>
```

Or with `tf.reshape`:

```
def Kmodel(x, params):
    y = tf.repeat(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), repeats=tf.shape(params)[0])
    y = tf.reshape(y, (tf.shape(params)[0], tf.shape(x)[0]))

    return tf.keras.backend.cos(tf.expand_dims(params[:, 0], axis=-1)* x)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for the quick reply. I'm quite a noob in NN and coming from more explicit languages I never understood the reshaping and such.